# Detect endpoints of a line

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to detect the points shown in the image below:

[image: Image Link]

I have done this so far:

```
[X,map] = rgb2ind(img,0.0);
img = ind2gray(X,map);    % Convert indexed to grayscale
level = graythresh(img);   % Compute an appropriate threshold
img_bw = im2bw(img,level);% Convert grayscale to binary
mask = zeros(size(img_bw));
mask(2:end-2,2:end-2) = 1;
img_bw(mask<1) = 1;
%invert image
img_inv =1-img_bw;
% find blobs
img_blobs = bwmorph(img_inv,'majority',10);
% figure, imshow(img_blobs);
[rows, columns] = size(img_blobs);
for col = 1 : columns
    thisColumn = img_blobs(:, col);
    topRow = find(thisColumn, 1, 'first');
    bottomRow = find(thisColumn, 1, 'last');
    img_blobs(topRow : bottomRow, col) = true;
end
inverted = imcomplement(img_blobs);
ed = edge(inverted,'canny');
figure, imshow(ed),title('inverted');
```

Now how to proceed to get the coordinates of the desired position?

Answer (score 1):

The top point is obviously the white pixel with the highest ordinate, which is easily obtained.

The bottom point is not so well defined. What you can do is

- follow the peak edges until you reach a local minimum, on the left and on the right. That gives you a line segment, which you can intersect with the vertical through the top point.
- if you know a the peak width, try every pixel on the vertical through the top point, downward, and stop until it has no left nor right neighbors at a distance equal to the peak with.
- as above, but stop when the distance between the left and right neighbors exceeds a threshold.

Comment: Yes I can find the top point.  The idea you told also came to my mind  to find the bottom point as the intersection of two lines. Which seems hard for me to code. In that case even If I do not want find the exact middle point but any point closest to it, left or right. Then what could be the possible way?

Comment: "Which seems hard for me code": come on, it's not !

Comment: @user8126672 you cannot find that point if you don't define what this point is. without a clear definition that allows to develop a robust algorithm you will only end up with some poor code that works for this very image and nothing else. otherwise you could just use your mouse to pick that point...

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you could consider using `houghlines` in matlab. Setting the required `Theta` and `MinLength` parameter values, you should be able to get the two vertical lines parallel to your peak. You can use the end points of the vertical lines, to get the point at the bottom.

Here is a sample code.

```
[H,theta,rho] = hough(bw,'Theta',5:1:30);%This is the angle range
P = houghpeaks(H,500,'NHoodSize',[11 11]);
lines = houghlines(bw,theta,rho,P,'FillGap',10,'MinLength',300);
```

[Here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html) is a complete description of how `houghlines` actually works.